# UIKit ViewController ===> into SwiftUI ContentView

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, uikit, facebook-audience-network

Trying to integrate Facebook audience Network ad placements into my SwiftUI project.

The tutorial published by Facebook assumes the use of UIKit only!
With zero experience in UIKit, need your kind help to enable me to integrate the follwing lines of code into my ContentView as a SwiftUI view:

```
    //Add a UIView element to the main View element and name it to adContainer. 
    //Now, in your View Controller header file (or Swift file, if you are a Swift user), 
    //import FBAudienceNetwork, declare conformance to the FBAdViewDelegate protocol, 
    //and add an instance variable for the ad unit
        
            
            import UIKit
            import FBAudienceNetwork
            
            class ViewController: UIViewController, FBAdViewDelegate {
                
                @IBOutlet private var adContainer: UIView!
                
                private var adView: FBAdView?
            }

    //Add the code below to viewDidLoad; Create a new instance of FBAdView and add it to the view. 
    //FBAdView is a subclass of UIView. You can add it to your view hierarchy just like any other view.
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Instantiate an AdView object.
        // NOTE: the placement ID will eventually identify this as your app, you can ignore while you
        // are testing and replace it later when you have signed up.
        // While you are using this temporary code you will only get test ads and if you release
        // your code like this to the App Store your users will not receive ads (you will get a 'No Fill' error).
        let adView = FBAdView(placementID: "YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID", adSize: kFBAdSizeHeight50Banner, rootViewController: self)
        adView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 250)
        adView.delegate = self
        adView.loadAd()
        self.adView = adView
    }
//Optionally, you can add the following functions to handle the cases 
//where the ad is closed or when the user clicks on it:

func adViewDidClick(_ adView: FBAdView) {
    print("Ad was clicked.")
}

func adViewDidFinishHandlingClick(_ adView: FBAdView) {
    print("Ad did finish click handling.")
}

func adViewWillLogImpression(_ adView: FBAdView) {
    print("Ad impression is being captured.")
}

//Add and implement the following two delegate functions in your 
//View Controller to handle ad loading failures:

func adView(_ adView: FBAdView, didFailWithError error: Error) {
  print("Ad failed to load with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

func adViewDidLoad(_ adView: FBAdView) {
  print("Ad was loaded and ready to be displayed")
  showAd()
}

private func showAd() {
  guard let adView = adView, adView.isAdValid else {
    return
  }
  adContainer.addSubview(adView)
}
```

Your help would be tremendously appreciated would be

Comment: Wrap it in UIViewControllerRepresentable. Apple has a tutorial about integrating UIKit into SwiftUI that covers this.

Comment: @jnpdx I tried doing just that but it didn't work. I just can'g get my hand around the concept of UIViewControllerRepresentable & interactivity between SwiftUI & UIKit. Any sensical tutorial on this particular case (Facebook Audience Network) be appreciated.